# Laraver InnerJoin with QueryBuilder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i have this below code to join with `webInformation` and `weblinks` with `webLink` field.

```
   $getResult = DB::table('webInformation')
        ->join('webLinks', function($join)
                {
                    $join->on('webLinks.id', '=', 'webInformation.weblink');
                })
        ->get();
```

this query get Result error :

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ads.weblinks' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `webInformation` inner join `weblinks` on `weblinks`.`id` = `webInformation`.`weblink`
```

but i can get succesful result in phpMyadmin.

**Models :**
webInformation:

```
class webInformation extends Eloquent{

    protected $table='webInformation';
}
```

**webLinks:**

```
class webLinks extends Eloquent{

    protected $table='weblinks';
}
```

Tables:

[image: phpMyadmin]

all tables and fields are correct.

**toSql Command:**

```
$getResult = DB::table('webInformation')
                ->join('weblinks', function($join)
                        {
                            $join->on('weblinks.id', '=', 'webInformation.weblink');
                        })
                ->toSql‬();
```

**toSql Result:**

```
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toSql‬()
```

**Framework Version:**

```
Laravel Framework version 4.1.23
```

Comment: what happens if you don't include a closure and write in plain way? _your query doesn't need a closure to make matter complicated_

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `DB::table()` instead you may `Eloquent` way:

```
$result = WebInformation::join('webInformation.weblink', '=', 'webLinks.id')->get();
```

Or this:

```
$result = DB::table('WebInformation')->join('webInformation.weblink', '=', 'webLinks.id')->get();
```

This should work:

```
$sql = WebInformation::join('webInformation.weblink', '=', 'webLinks.id')->toSql();
```

You can also use this to log the last query:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```